# store $_POST content in multiple categories php

Tags: php, sql, post

I want to store text snippets, which are sent to database via form ($_POST) in multiple categories.

Therefore i have 3 main tables in my database

1. Content --> Text snippets are stored here ( ID, Content )
2. Categories --> All existing categories are stored here (Cat_ID, Cat_Name)
3. Relationships --> All realtionships should be stored here, for example

I post a text snippet in two categories, therefore i want to store the ID of the text snippet and the category id in the relationship table. For two categories it should be two entries.

**this snippet echos all categories to checkboxes**

```
// SELECT CATEGORIES FROM TABLE tbl_jokes_category
function leweb_categories_from_database() {
$conn = useDB();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_jokes_categories";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //tm($row);
        echo "<input type='checkbox' id=" .$row["id_categories"] ." name=leweb_joke_categories_" .$row["id_categories"] . " value=". $row["slug"]. "> " . utf8_encode($row["name"]) . "<br />";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

}

**this snippet inserts data in database, but its only for one category now** i would like to modify it, that the text snippet is stored like now, and the categories are stored in the relationship table (now the are stored in the content table )

```
// INSERT DATA INTO DATABASE
if(count($_POST)>0) {
    tm($_POST);

    $sql = "
        INSERT INTO tbl_jokes 
            (content, rid_jokes_categories)
                VALUES (
                        '" . $_POST["leweb_joke_content"] . "',
                        '" . $_POST["leweb_joke_categories"] . "'   
                        )
    ";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        tm("New record created successfully");
    } 
    else {
        tm("Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error);
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Your INSERT query is vulnerable to injection attack; you should be using a prepared statement.  You don't need `>0` in either of your scripts.  What is your best attempt to self-solve?  `leweb` looks like a framwork/cms prefix -- are you developing inside of a known system?

Comment: no leweb is my own prefix for functions - its coded by myself 100% - what do you mean with prepared statement?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php  (and you also don't need to write `=== TRUE`)

Comment: My best attempt was: trying to get all categories in one array ( i already did this ) and then check on $_POST if such an entry exists - but this seems not to be a solution

Comment: I think you have abstracted your data structure too far.  Why not have a Category column in Content?  I think this should be done in two tables, not three.

Comment: Yes that would be possible, but than i have the problem that i can only post two 2 or 3 categories - what if i need more categories for the snippets in the future... then i always have to change the code and the database

the structure i use above is the same structure as used in wordpress, but i dont know how to code i right... no ideas or hints for me?

Comment: You are in no way limit by using properly structured Content and Categories tables.  Both will be expandable.  If you want more Categories, you only need to add more rows to the Categories table.

Comment: but is this the right way to do it? the above way is more flexible... do you think that a solution is to much of coding?

Comment: You can do whatever you like.  I've stated what I would do.